# Optimal way to draw lines and polygons dynamically on Nutiteq map?

Tags: android, maps, navigation-drawer, nutiteq

I have been working on nutiteq maps, and I need to draw a trace over map, as my location changes, but it should be with different width(5m, 10m) and need to calculate where its overlapping itself. I draw lines dinamicly with line.setVertexList(arr_lat_long), but I think that this isn't an good approach to do this job. Think to draw them like a polygons, because then will calculate overlapping with JTS. But it will be very slow operation :/. Is there an another way to draw over the map, some other paint tool or lib to help me. The purpose is to fill some area with these traces..

Thanks

Comment: It may help if you describe more (best with some drawings) what you really want to do here. Make an app to measure some areas? And provide your code samples (and sample data) to see what operation with what data is exactly slow there.